# Getting a table out of a GLPK solution throws error "Assertion failed: out != out"

Tags: glpk

I have a linear program in a file `lp` that GLPK solves with this command:

```
glpsol --math -m lp
```

Part of the output on the screen is:

```
Generating priority_words...
Model has been successfully generated
...
Long-step dual simplex will be used
+   770: mip =     not found yet <=              +inf        (1; 0)
Solution found by heuristic: 1569225
...
INTEGER OPTIMAL SOLUTION FOUND
...
Writing MIP solution to 'result'...
```

The file `result` is unformatted and I want to save the results in CSV. So I include a line to output the results to a table right after the last constraint and before the `end;` keyword:

```
...
s.t. priority_words{w in words}: include[w] >= priority[w];

table num{u in unicodes} OUT "CSV" "num.csv": u~unicode, number_of_characters[u]~count;

end;
```

And GLPK gives this error:

```
Generating priority_words...
Writing num...
Assertion failed: out != out
Error detected in file mpl/mpl3.c at line 5072
Abort trap: 6
```

Neither the [wikibook](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/GLPK/Table_Statement) nor the gmpl manual in the distribution (at `doc/gmpl.pdf`) have an example of getting a table out of GLPK.

How can I ask GLPK for a table of results after solving the model?

Comment: The assertion should never be reached. Please, send a mail including the model file to bug-glpk@gnu.org. Cf. https://lists.gnu.org/mailman/listinfo/bug-glpk

Comment: @Xypron No, indeed it shouldn't! The reason is that I am a newbie with GLPK and forgot to add a `solve;` before asking to output a table. I wrote that as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that the output for the code with the `table OUT` statement does not have the line `Model has been successfully generated`. Therefore GLPK attempted to write the table of results before solving the problem! The sample code [in this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40413044/formating-output-csv-files-in-glpk) shows that GLPK needs to know when to solve the problem, otherwise it solves it at the end. So just add `solve;` before the table:

```
...
s.t. priority_words{w in words}: include[w] >= priority[w];
solve;
table num{u in unicodes} OUT "CSV" "num.csv": u~unicode, number_of_characters[u]~count;
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

> Neither the wikibook nor the gmpl manual in the distribution (at doc/gmpl.pdf) have an example of getting a table out of GLPK.

The current version of GLPK is 4.65. The lines below relate to this version.

Examples are in:

- examples/csv
- examples/sql
- examples/dbf

doc/gmpl.pdf has a chapter on the table statement.

Comment: Yes, I read that chapter and learned the syntax, but still couldn't find a working example in the manual.